# Construct a new data frame by merging two rows of an existing data frame using common column values in both the row

Tags: r, dataframe

https://www.dropbox.com/s/prqiojwzpax339z/Test123.xlsx?dl=0

The link contains an xlsx file which contains the details of a batsman batting  in one sheet where runs scored in each innings by him in a test match is recorded.So the details of the rows contains identical values w.r.t some columns between two rows because in a test match a batsman gets the chance to bat in two innings so details mentioned in columns like opposition,Ground,StartDateAscending,MatchNumber,Result will be common when we compare two rows for a test match.

Question:so how can we club the data present in the rows based on this matching values and create a new data frame with merged rows.

Ex:In data shared through the link,i am  taking the first two rows as a sample to tell what i want to achieve and below is the text representation of the r object of this sample data derived using r function

```
structure(list(Runs = c("10", "27"), Mins = c("30", "93"), BF = c("19", 
"65"), X4s = c("1", "4"), X6s = c("0", "0"), SR = c("52.63", 
"41.53"), Pos = c("6", "6"), Dismissal = c("bowled", "caught"
), Inns = c(2, 4), Opposition = c("v England", "v England"), 
    Ground = c("Lord's", "Lord's"), Start.DateAscending = structure(c(648930600, 
    648930600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    Match.Number = c("Test # 1148", "Test # 1148"), Result = c("Loss", 
    "Loss")), .Names = c("Runs", "Mins", "BF", "X4s", "X6s", 
"SR", "Pos", "Dismissal", "Inns", "Opposition", "Ground", "Start.DateAscending", 
"Match.Number", "Result"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

The data derived from the above block will be something like below:

```
  Runs Mins BF X4s X6s    SR Pos Dismissal Inns Opposition Ground
1   10   30 19   1   0 52.63   6    bowled    2  v England Lord's
2   27   93 65   4   0 41.53   6    caught    4  v England Lord's
  Start.DateAscending Match.Number Result
1          1990-07-26  Test # 1148   Loss
2          1990-07-26  Test # 1148   Loss
```

So what i want to achieve is to sum up the runs column values based on the common column values like Match.Number,Opposition,Ground,Start.DateAscending.

I expect  the values like below which will be stored in a new data frame

```
 Runs   Opposition  Ground Start.DateAscending Match.Number Result
1   37     v England Lord's 1990-07-26          Test # 1148   Loss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We subset the columns of the dataset, using `aggregate` after conveting the 'Runs' to `numeric` class

```
colsofinterest <- names(df1)[c(1, 10:ncol(df1))]
aggregate(Runs~., df1[colsofinterest], sum)
#  Opposition Ground Start.DateAscending Match.Number Result Runs
#1  v England Lord's          1990-07-26  Test # 1148   Loss   37
```

---

Or we can use `tidyverse`

```
colsofinterest2 <- names(df1)[10:ncol(df1)]
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by_(.dots = colsofinterest2) %>%
    summarise(Runs = sum(Runs))
# A tibble: 1 x 6
# Groups: Opposition, Ground, Start.DateAscending, Match.Number [?]
#  Opposition Ground Start.DateAscending Match.Number Result  Runs
#       <chr>  <chr>              <dttm>        <chr>  <chr> <int>
#1  v England Lord's          1990-07-26  Test # 1148   Loss    37
```